# Bold First Occurence in a Series Only Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have a long list of equipment like this;

[image]

I would like to be able to run a VBA script that allows excel to change the format of the first of a series so that they are more visible. Is this a possibility?

[image: Example of what I'm trying to do]

This is housed in an excel table, not sure if that has an impact.

Comment: This does not need vba.  It can be done with Conditional Formatting.

Comment: How? @ScottCraner

Comment: Use a formula: `=COUNTIF($A$1:$A1,$A1)=1` assuming you are using column A as the column with the data.  Then set the format for that rule correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You could iterate through the range update format if below cell<>previous cell.

```
Sub UpdateCatHead(ByRef rng As Range, Optional col_index As Integer = 1)
    Dim rng_search As Range
    'lets ,make sure to have range of one column
    Set rng_search = rng.Columns(col_index)
    Dim cell As Range, prev_cell As Range
    Dim prev_cat As String
    For Each cell In rng_search.Cells
        'check if empty is empty and exit for?
        If cell.Row = 1 Then
            'update cell to bold here
            Debug.Print (cell.Row)
        Else
            Set prev_cell = cell.Worksheet.Cells(cell.Row - 1, cell.Column) 'cell above
            If CStr(cell.Value) <> CStr(prev_cell.Value) Then
                'update cell to bold here
                Debug.Print (cell.Row)
            End If
        End If
    Next cell
End Sub
```

call Sub like this:

```
UpdateCatHead ThisWorkbook.Sheets("data").Range("A1:A100")
```